# get all values from select play framework

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I have form with select item, which I'm filling on client side.

```
    <table>
        <td>
            <tr>
                <input type="text" id="textValue">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <button type="button" onclick="insertVal()">Insert option</button>
            </tr>
        </td>
        <td>
                <select id="properties" size="6" name="properties" multiple>
                </select>
        </td>
    </table>
<script>
    function insertVal() {
        var x = document.getElementById("properties");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = document.getElementById("textValue").value;
        x.add(option, x[0]);
        document.getElementById("textValue").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

I need to get this values in java code in my controller.
I tried something like this, but it passes only selected value.

```
DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
Logger.info(requestData.get("properties"));
```

Comment: Why do you use a select when you also want the values that are NOT selected?

Comment: I need to collect some properties for input data. So code, enclosed in a tag <table>, is an input form for properties.

Comment: It does not make sense and you are not answering my earlier question. But, if you insist on using a `select`: you need to mark each element that you add as `selected`, otherwise it is not sent to server side. So in `insertVal()` you need something like `option.prop('selected', true)`..

Comment: I came to this decision too. It might be wrong solution to use select item. What I need to add some strings and display them all, and only then make   request to save page. Is there any more usual way doing this?

Comment: Well, you can use hidden form elements and wrap your strings within a nice `p`. You can style them more easily then a `select with multiple`..

Comment: I can't figure out how to receive params to controller.

Comment: You have to provide a sample, perhaps create a repository with your code on https://github.com

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was busy a little bit. 
Here is files I'm dealing with.
https://github.com/IamEgor/PlayTest/blob/master/app/views/TEMP_fields_uu_id.scala.html
https://github.com/IamEgor/PlayTest/blob/master/app/controllers/Actions.java
I don't know how to save all values in dropdown select item.

Comment: I have created 2 pull requests, merge those and review the changes to see what I have done, ok?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've come to the similar decision. 
`Map<String, String[]> values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();\r
String[] strings = values.get("propsList");`
Thanks again.